# Los datos no aparecen en el listado, solo las columnas

Tags: jspdf

estoy utilizando el jsPDF y el jspdf-autotable y generé un informe, pero me encuentro con la dificultad de que solo figuran en el PDF, el encabezado. A continuación les comparto el código:

crearPDF(){

```
  var columns = [
    {title: "Nombre", datakey: "nombre"},
    {title: "Código", datakey: "codigo"},
    {title: "Categoría", datakey: "categoria"},
    {title: "Stock", datakey: "stock"},
    {title: "Precio Venta", datakey: "precio_venta"}
  ];

  var rows=[];

  this.articulos.map(function(x){
    rows.push(
    {nombre:x.nombre,
    codigo:x.codigo,
    categoria:x.categoria.nombre,
    stock:x.stock,
    precio_venta:x.precio_venta}
    );
  });

  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  doc.autoTable(columns,rows,{
      margin: {top: 60},
      didDrawPage: function(data){
          doc.text("Lista de Artículos", 40, 30);
      }
  });
  //console.log(rows);
  doc.save('Articulos.pdf');
},
```

y aquí el error de la consola:

Use of deprecated autoTable initiation

Comment: pudiste solucionar amigo tengo el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

en la sección:

```
{title: "Nombre", "nombre"},
{title: "Código",  "codigo"},
{title: "Categoría",  "categoria"},
{title: "Stock", "stock"},
{title: "Precio Venta",  "precio_venta"}
```

Debes quitar datakey:

Answer (score 0):

El `datakey` está minúsculas. Con que lo cambies a `dataKey` como aparece en el código abajo debería funcionar:

```
var columns = [
    {title: "Nombre", dataKey: "nombre"},
    {title: "Código", dataKey: "codigo"},
    {title: "Categoría", dataKey: "categoria"},
    {title: "Stock", dataKey: "stock"},
    {title: "Precio Venta", dataKey: "precio_venta"}
  ];
```

EL resto del código está bien. Así debería mostrar los datos.